# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':qr_code_scanner:classpath'

Tags: android, flutter

**Am unable to get around this error after upgrading flutter version to 3.0.4. from version 2.10**

***Error***

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':qr_code_scanner'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':qr_code_scanner:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
     Required by:
     project :qr_code_scanner
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with     Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10:
      - gradle70JavadocElements
      - gradle70RuntimeElements
      - gradle70SourcesElements
      - javadocElements
      - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
      - sourcesElements
    All of them match the consumer attributes:
      - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Unmatched attributes:
              - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
              - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
              - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
      - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Unmatched attributes:
              - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
      - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Unmatched attributes:
              - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
              - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
              - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
      - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Unmatched attributes:
              - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with     Java 11)
              - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
              - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
      - Variant 'runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Unmatched attributes:
              - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
      - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Unmatched attributes:
              - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
              - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
              - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
    The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
      - Variant 'apiElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
      - Variant 'gradle70ApiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':qr_code_scanner' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':qr_code_scanner' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

***I dont understand where the issue is. Any assistance will be much appreciated***

*gradle file*

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'  // Google Services plugin
 }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

*Flutter doctor output*

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889], locale en-us)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.67.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

i have tried changing kotlin versions manually but didn't work, also tried building the app from clean workstation and got the same error, reduced the qr scanner version from 4.0 to 1.0 but no fruits

Answer (score 0):

**This will work :)**

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```